# use fine-tuned BERT to train a new sentence-transformer

Tags: nlp, bert-language-model

I have fine-tuned BERT on domain specific data, now I am going to train a sentence transformer based on this fine-tuned BERT and my own labelled data. I created sentence transformer by below code:

```
model_name = "path/to/model" 
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased") # when I fine tuned the BERT, I used this tokenizer
model = AutoModel.from_pretrained(model_name)

word_embedding_model = models.Transformer(model, tokenizer)
pooling_model = models.Pooling(word_embedding_model.get_word_embedding_dimension())
sentence_transformer = SentenceTransformer(modules=[word_embedding_model, pooling_model])
```

but I got error:

```
We couldn't connect to 'https://huggingface.co' to load this model, couldn't find it in the cached files and it looks like BertModel(...)  is not the path to a directory containing a {configuration_file} file.
Checkout your internet connection or see how to run the library in offline mode at 'https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/installation#offline-mode'.
```

I saved to google drive by below code:

```
model.save_pretrained('/content/drive/MyDrive/testForSentTransformer')
```

and got below two errors:

```
HFValidationError: Repo id must use alphanumeric chars or '-', '_', '.', '--' and '..' are forbidden, '-' and '.' cannot start or end the name, max length is 96: 'BertModel(
  (embeddings): BertEmbeddings(
    (word_embeddings): Embedding(30522, 768, padding_idx=0)
    (position_embeddings): Embedding(512, 768)
    (token_type_embeddings): Embedding(2, 768)
    (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
    (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
  )
```

and

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/transformers/configuration_utils.py in _get_config_dict(cls, pretrained_model_name_or_path, **kwargs)
    647             except Exception:
    648                 # For any other exception, we throw a generic error.
--> 649                 raise EnvironmentError(
    650                     f"Can't load the configuration of '{pretrained_model_name_or_path}'. If you were trying to load it"
    651                     " from 'https://huggingface.co/models', make sure you don't have a local directory with the same"

OSError: Can't load the configuration of 'BertModel(
  (embeddings): BertEmbeddings(
    (word_embeddings): Embedding(30522, 768, padding_idx=0)
    (position_embeddings): Embedding(512, 768)
    (token_type_embeddings): Embedding(2, 768)
    (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
    (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
  )
```

how to fix these errors? Thanks for helping!

Comment: Can you share the files present in `path/to/model`? It seems there is something wrong with the file path.

Comment: I saved to huggingface hub, the 'path/to/model' is 'username/modelname', I just ran code in google colab, and saved to google drive, and got a new error as the picture. Thanks.

Comment: Please include error messages as strings and not images, such that it can appear in future searches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

should do:

```
model_path = "path/to/model" 
# tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased") 
# model = AutoModel.from_pretrained(model_name)

word_embedding_model = models.Transformer(model_name_or_path=model_path, tokenizer_name_or_path="bert-base-uncased")
pooling_model = models.Pooling(word_embedding_model.get_word_embedding_dimension())
sentence_transformer = SentenceTransformer(modules=[word_embedding_model, pooling_model])
```